# Can't install Dragon NaturallySpeaking with Wine on Hera

Tags: release-hera, wine

I got rid of Windows, so I need to install [Dragon NaturallySpeaking 11.5](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23880) using Wine. On Wine AppDB, it has silver status, but still I wasn't able to install it. The tutorials I found say “choose manual installation” but that button just doesn't exist (or at least isn't shown) in my case.

Here is a screenshot of how the installation menu is looking:

[image: installation menu]

I tried every wine version available in the AppCenter (playonlinux first!) but I couldn't get to the manual installation process. It would be so great to get this working. Can you help?

Thanks in advance!
Jo

Comment: Hello Jo! This is a very specific question, you'll probably have better luck if you ask on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), since there isn't any difference between Wine on Elementary and on Ubuntu. Also, the test on Wine AppDB says “NatSpeak 11.5 installs pretty much flawlessly into a Windows 8 wineprefix.” Have you installed Dragon into a Windows 8 wineprefix?

Comment: Also: PlayOnLinux is a very broken app and probably isn't maintainied anymore. You can probably deal with the app just with pure Wine, but if you want a sandbox for Wine with good UI, try [Lutris](https://lutris.net/).